# Parsing and Storing Data in Realtime

Tags: java, android, parsing, background-process

I've built a bandwidth monitor app which successfully uploads data to parse.com using the following:

```
   testObject.put("dataOutput", String.valueOf(mStartTX));
```

However the data is always stored as zero. The reason for this is the initial value of the long/string I'm sending IS zero (when the app first starts) however it is constantly changing as the user begins to send and receive data. Can this data be parsed in realtime somehow? Or resent every few seconds as the data changes?

FULL SOURCE:

```
public class ParseStarterProjectActivity extends Activity {
TextView textSsid, textSpeed, textRssi;

public Handler mHandler = new Handler();
public long mStartRX = 0;
public long mStartTX = 0;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.parser);
textSsid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Ssid);
textSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Speed);
textRssi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Rssi);
Long.toString(mStartTX);
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
testObject.put("dataOutput", String.valueOf(mStartTX));
testObject.saveInBackground();


mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
if (mStartRX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED || mStartTX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED)     AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setTitle("Uh Oh!");
alert.setMessage("Your device does not support traffic stat monitoring.");
alert.show();
} else {
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
}
}
private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
TextView RX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RX);
TextView TX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TX);
long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX;
RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes));
long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()- mStartTX;
TX.setText(Long.toString(txBytes));
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to create an IntentService that runs while your app is running (or maybe even when it's closed).  Collect your data using an AlarmService so it wakes up on a set iteration to collect the data.  The AlarmService is designed to be battery friendly.

```
private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() { // ... }
```

That Runnable is a great idea in Java; not so much in Android.  If you just need to get off the UI thread consider an AsyncTask() or similar -- but, as noted above, a background service is probably a better choice.  I don't know what your familiarity with Java or naming conventions are so maybe this is just a simple oversight, but `mRunnable` should be just `runnable` in your code.  Variables prefixed with an "m" or an "_" (underscore) are fields like your `mHandler`, `mStartTX` and `mStartRX`.

Also, the solo line `Long.toString(mStartTX);` does nothing.

Comment: I'm incredibly new to all this. I just read the following tutorial:http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html and I think I understand the general concept but the exact way to implement it in this scenario - I have no idea...

Comment: Does something like this look correct?Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1*1000, pintent);

Comment: Does it work?  ;)  There are a lot of ways you can implement what I pointed you toward.

Comment: Negative. (I wish it was!)

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html as you already noted.  The answer is in there.  I promise.